# Is it possible to make the type of raw_input an integer or string depending on the input itself?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, integer

I'm trying to make a number guessing game in which the user guesses the number. Ideally, I'd like to take both the integer and string version of the number as valid answers. From what I know, I would have to set raw_input as an integer or leave it (as a string) and then make an if statement that converts the input to an integer or string if it is different from the starting data type. I also am confused about how I can format the else statement using string concatenation if %s is for strings but %d is for integers. I apologize for any rookie mistakes I've made in the post or in the code, I just started a few weeks ago. This is the part of my code that is tripping me up:

```
call = int(raw_input('Guess: ')) #defining for use outside of the function definitions

if call.isalpha():
  str(call)

def call_and_response():
  if call == 76 or call.lower() == 'seventy-six':
    print 'Fantastic! 76 is correct. \nThank you for playing!'
  else:
    print 'Good try, but %s is incorrect.' %(call)
      
call_and_response()
```

Comment: Why are you still using Python 2.7?

Comment: @Barmar Have to, it's for my intro computer science course.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isdigit()` to tell if the input is a number.

```
call = raw_input('Guess: ')
if call.isdigit():
    call = int(call)
    correct = call == 76
else:
    correct = call.lower() == 'seventy-six'
if correct:
    print 'Fantastic! 76 is correct'
else:
    print 'Good try'
```